# User wants PHP to be able to write files in his directory

Tags: security, php, usermod

The user wants to let PHP write files in his /home/ directory, he is advising me to do `usermod -a -G www-data username` where `username` is his username. I wasn't sure if this was a security issue or not.

What is the best way approaching this?

Comment: Given the setting (multi-user, web server), this question looks like material for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed command adds the user to the `www-data` group. This may give him unintended extra permissions, in particular he'll be able to access any file that's restricted to the `www-data` group. This is probably a lot more than you intended.

For example, suppose two users make this request and get added to the `www-data` group, and each user opens up `~/www-shared` to the `www-data` group. Then each will be able to read and write to the other's `www-shared` directory.

Access control lists look a lot more appropriate for the stated purpose. This requires that your operating system and filesystem support ACLs. On Linux, make sure that the filesystem is mounted with the `acl` option. Then the user can run `setfacl -m user:www-data:rwx ~/www-shared` to share a directory with the `www-data` user.

Still, this problem sounds like something many people running web servers have faced before. So there may be a much better solution involving the Apache toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea because the user www-data will be in the group of the user. So the webserver may manipulate all files of this user.

Also, any other users on the system are then able to read and write from the files of the given user via a simple php script.

It's generally not a good idea to give the webserver more write/read access, than needed. So you might want to widen the permissions only in the directory (or even on the file) which needs write access. This can be an upload directory, for example.

like...

```
chgrp www-data /home/foobar/public_html/wordpress/uploads
chmod -R g+rwX /home/foobar/public_html/wordpress/uploads
```

Comment: Do you mean the user will be apart of the www-data group?

Comment: No, BHare.. That way the server is just able to write to the one specified directory instead of everything in /home/foo/.

Comment: Addition: the command your user suggested makes the user "www-data" belonging to the group of that given user. See `man usermod`

Comment: I always thought `usermod -a -G <group> <user>`  would append the <group> to <user>, but your saying the syntax is `usermod -a -G <user> <group>`. Strangly then, when i do `id username` it shows him apart of the www-data group.

Comment: Oh hell! You're correct! The last parameter is the username which will be in the www-data group then. Sorry for my false statement.
So this situation is even more worse now. I'd remove him from this group ASAP and I'd stick to the smallest possible solution: chmod/chgrp *only* the directory where write access is needed. Not a whole web-root. And -if possible- move the write-enabled directories out of the document-root.